# Haskell - Funções de Ordem Superior

Tags: haskell

```
(a) any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

que teste se um predicado é verdade para
algum elemento de uma lista; por exemplo:

```
any odd [1..10] == True

(b) zipWith :: (a->b->c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

que combina os elementos de
duas listas usando uma função especı́fica; por exemplo:

```
zipWith (+) [1,2,3,4,5] [10,20,30,40] == [11,22,33,44].
```

Comment: Por favor, formule melhor a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Ficam aqui alternativas para uma implementação das duas funções.

`myAny` é uma função que recebe como argumentos um predicado e uma lista genérica e devolve Verdadeiro/True se algum dos elementos respeita o predicado.

O predicado é uma função `a -> Bool` que devolve Verdadeiro ou Falso de acordo com a variável passada como parâmetro. Como exemplos tem `odd, even, (2==), (>3)`.

```
myAny:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny f (x:xs) 
              | f x == True = True
              | otherwise = myAny f xs
myAny _ [] = False
```

O caso `_ [] = False` é trivial (lista vazia). Quando a lista tem elementos, a ideia é iterar sobre cada um dos elementos até atingir o final da lista ou um elemento que respeite o predicado.

`myZipWith` é uma função que devolve uma lista que resulta da aplicação de uma função aos elementos de duas listas, elementos estes que ocorrem na mesma posição.

```
myZipWith:: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]                  
myZipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : myZipWith f xs ys
myZipWith _ _ _ = []
```